# Look up the shape which contains an X,Y coordinate

Tags: java, algorithm, geospatial

I have a collection of `java.awt.Shape` objects covering a two-dimensional plane with no overlap. These are from a data set of U.S. Counties, at a fairly low resolution. For an (x,y) latitude/longitude point, I want a quick way to identify the shape which county contains that point. What's an optimal way to index this?

Brute force would look like:

```
    for (Shape eachShape : countyShapes) {
        if (eachShape.contains(x, y)) {
            return eachShape;
        }
    }
```

To optimize this, I can store the min/max bounds of the (possibly complex) shapes, and only call `contains(x, y)` on shapes whose rectangular bounds encompass a given x,y coordinate. What's the best way to build this index? A [SortedMultiset](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/SortedMultiset.html) would work for indexing on the `x` minima and maxima, but how to also include the `y` coordinates in the index?

For this specific implementation, doing a few seconds of up-front work to index the shapes is not a problem.

Comment: The question is very broad, and likely *too* broad. There are dozens of spatial data structures out there, ranging from the (famous) Quadtrees, kD-Trees and BSP to things like [spatial hashing](https://conkerjo.wordpress.com/2009/06/13/spatial-hashing-implementation-for-fast-2d-collisions/). In most cases, there are several trade-offs regarding the memory consumption, precision, query time vs. build time and so on. Or is the question *specifically* about how to solve this with a `SortedMultiSet`?

Comment: Thanks @Marco13, this is for U.S. county data, startup time is not an issue. I'm fetching thousands of addresses on a single request, and need to group them by county as quickly as possible, so the end-user experience is speedy.

Comment: This adds some important information (which could have been part of the question, to narrow it a bit): So the number of shapes will be ~3000. They will have "similar" sizes. They'll be simple and "mostly convex". Maybe others can give hints based on that. I cannot give a specific recommendation here. My approach would be to hide this behind an interface (very simple, single method: `Collection<Identifier> get(Point p)`), and try out/benchmark some implementations. Many of them can likely be found out-of-the box in existing libraries.

Comment: @Marco13 I'm not sure they are of 'similar' sizes or 'mostly' convex. http://www.city-data.com/forum/attachments/general-u-s/38702d1238143049-united-states-counties-map-us-map.jpg

Comment: @DanAllen The "similar" was in quotes: The sizes don't vary by a factor of 1000 or so, which is at least a rough hint. Their shapes are mostly convex in the sense that if one *bounding box* contains a point, the chance is usually >50% (often >90%) that the actual *shape* contains the point. But I'm not sure about the "simple" any more: Looking at https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Usa_counties_large.svg, there seem to be counties that are **"enclaves"** of other counties - if this is true, this could complicate things (**a lot**, potentially...)

Comment: @Macro13 I did think we're quibbling over terms. Maybe 'approximately' convex. That's certainly what makes most approximations poor. Shapes that aren't well approximated by a simple bounding box. They certainly pass that test. Actually if you look from the smallest to the largest there is a variation of x1000 in area (which is the revelvant metric here) compare San Bernadino, Ca. to Kalawao, Hi. But the variation isn't massively gross or lopsided in distribution.

Answer (score 1):

If possible you could try a bitmap with each shape in a different color. Then simply query the point and the color and lookup the shape.

Comment: This is certainly at the "very efficient but possibly imprecise" end of the trade-offs that I mentioned in the comments. It could be a *very* efficient and *very* simple solution. But it is always limited by the image resolution. Even for the [largest US counties image at Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/59/Usa_counties_large.svg/990px-Usa_counties_large.svg.png), some counties collapse into a blurry blob of a few pixels. For a *really* large image (>few thousand pixels), the resolution could be OK, but the memory consuption would be high...

Comment: But still thinking about pixelation it does offer a really simple way to partition. Just define an NxM array and store the counties in each cell that are in the corresponding cell of an NxM grid laid over the top of the map. That gives you N and M as tuning parameters. With about 3000 objects a relatively small grid would give you a considerably pared down list to check in detail. A Bbinary Space Partition will always be better but that might give an easy solution that's fit for purpose.

Comment: @DanAllen This is roughly what the spatial hashing is doing: It defines a grid, and stores in each cell a list of counties that overlap this cell. Depending on the grid size, this will be 1 county in most cases. For a given point, the cell is found via O(1) lookup, and only "few" counties really have to be checked. (yes, "few" - there's the quibbling again ;-))

Answer (score 1):

This question is outside the scope of Stackoverflow but the answer is probably [Binary Space Partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning).

Roughly:

1. Divide the space in two either on the x coordinate or y coordinate using the mid-point of the range.
2. Create a list of counties on the two sides of that line (and divided by that line).
3. On each side of that line divide the collections again by the other dimension.
4. Continue recursively building a tree dividing alternately by x and y until you reach a satisfactory set of objects to examine by brute force.

The conventional algorithm actually divides the shapes lying across the boundary but that might not be necessary here.

A smart implementation might look for the most efficient line to divide on which is the one where the longest of the two lists is the smallest.
That involves more up front calculation but a more efficient and consistently performing partition.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an existing GIS library like [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) and then all the hard work is already done.

Simply load your [shapefile of counties](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_counties.html) and execute queries like

```
"the_geom" contains 'POINT(x y)
```

The [quickstart tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/index.html) will show you how to load the shapes, and the [query tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/filter/query.html) will show you how to query them.

Answer (score 0):

Having min an max values of coordinates of the bounds not guarantee that you can determine if one point is in or out in any situations. If you want achieve this by yourself you should implement some algorithm. There's a good one that is called "radial algorithm", I recommend that uses this, and it isn't so complicated to implement, there are sufficient bibliography and examples.
Hope this help.